# What is a good tutorial for peer-to-peer networking on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I would like to make a game where two players are connected via WiFi or Bluetooth, but I've not found any good tutorials out there on this.  What resources do you recommend for learning peer-to-peer networking on the iPhone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cover peer-to-peer networking, including Bonjour and Game Kit, as part of my course on iPhone development.  The notes for the respective class session can be found [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/Spring2010CourseNotes/networking.html), and the class can be downloaded as a video [from iTunes U](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/advanced-iphone-development-spring-2010/id407243032).

The notes also include links to simple example applications that show off peer-to-peer networking, and I demonstrate how all this works during the class.

Comment: Brad, which session is peer-to-peer covered?

Comment: @Brad Larson is it okay to use Game Kit for p2p connections for not a game app?

Comment: @flinth - Sure. Apple even shows how to do this in at least one WWDC session. I know I've seen non-game applications in the field that do this kind of local networking via Game Kit.

Comment: @BradLarson wow, that's very cool news :D, I was googling and found `NSNetService` class, I haven't got a big experience thats why I'm asking, I can you it for 2p2 too, as an alternative?

Answer (score 3):

To help with the network side, you'll probably want to use Game Kit, which can easily connect on BT or wifi.  Read Apple's doc on it!

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to start with the [Game Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).